# Grep command being reversed by special character?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to write a bash script which will search through a txt file for a string from another txt file which is stored within a variable.  However the string has a number of special characters in it and for some reason it seems to be corrupting the grep command.
The string is the following:
Sometxt ^/someurl/?$ http://somewebsite.com/

the grep command I'm using is

```
grep -v "$string" file.txt >> new_file.txt
```

This doesn't seem to work and if I echo the actual grep command using:

```
echo "grep -v \"$string\" file.txt >> new_file.txt"
```

I get an output that is all jumbled up.

If I enter the grep command manual and enter the actual string it works fine so I'm assuming that my shell is trying to expand the special characters but I don't how to escape all of them within the string.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: echo is a poor way to find out "What's really being executed" - use `set -x` for that.

Answer (score 5):

try fgrep (or `grep -F`)

By default grep interprets the search pattern as a basic regular expression, giving special meaning to characters like `.`, `$`, `^` `[]` etc

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this *might* help

```
grep -v "$(printf "%q" "$string")" file.txt >> new_file.txt
```

The bash builtin printf `%q` formatter escapes **shell** special characters.